# Sending an Email after countdown expires

Tags: javascript, meteor, countdown

I encountered a problem with my CountDown. I tried to send emails to some people i inserted in my collection before, when the counter expires `(t<=0)`. The problem is, its only getting fired when iam visiting the page. Is it anyhow possible that the server sends the emails when even noone is on the client side? I expect that i have to build something on the server side?

```
      Template.decision.onRendered(function(){
         clearInterval(timeinterval);
         timeinterval = setInterval(function () {
         var endtime = '2016/02/10'     
          Meteor.call("getCurrentTime", function (error, result) {
            Session.set("time", result);
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
            Session.set("t", t);
          });
        }, 1000);
      });


  function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Session.get('time');
    var seconds = ("0" + Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 )).slice(-2);
    var minutes = ("0" + Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 )).slice(-2);
    var hours = ("0" + Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 )).slice(-2);
    var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
    console.log(t);

    if(t <= 0 && timeinterval) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      var to = Questions.findOne({_id:selectedDecisionId}).email;
      var questionText = Questions.findOne({_id:selectedDecisionId}).questionDB;
      var nameCreater = Questions.findOne({_id:selectedDecisionId}).name;
      Meteor.call('sendEmail',to,questionText,nameCreater);
    }

return {
  'total': t,
  'days': days,
  'hours': hours,
  'minutes': minutes,
  'seconds': seconds
};
}
```

And on my server:

```
  Meteor.methods({
    'getCurrentTime': function (){
      return Date.parse(new Date());
    }
  });
```

Comment: why not just use one of the cron packages for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way to approach this is by using a *cron job* on the server. This is easily doable using the [percolate:synced-cron](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron) package.

```
SyncedCron.add({
  name: 'Send emails',
  schedule: function(parser) {
    // parser is a later.parse object
    return parser.text('every 1 minute');
  },
  job: function() {
    // find relevant, expired documents
    // send an email to each user that is affected
  }
});
```

Comment: but how do i get a connection between my countdown timer on the client side and the cron job on the server side then? what and where do i have to call this on the client side? i have different countdown timers with different endtimes, so i cant send an email to a fixed time.
 sorry i dont quite understand the solution. could you bring me on the right track?

Comment: Assuming you store the expiration time in a collection then you would find the users whose time had expired in the cron job and send them mail then mark them as sent to avoid multiple sends. There would be no countdown timer on the client and no need for the client to invoke a server method, the cron job would just run by itself on the server even if zero users were logged in.

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Session.get('time');
if (globalTimer) {
    // clear existing timer, so when new user enters we "restart" countdown
    clearTimeout(globalTimer);
}
globalTimer = setTimeout(function(){
    // execute here whatever you want when the timer expires
}, t);
```

Comment: i dont get this. where is the difference whether i call it inside my  `function getTimeRemaining(endtime){ if(t <= 0 && timeinterval) { // do anything }}` or in yours? why should the server now be able to send an email even when noone is on the client side?

Comment: because the last time a client was there you set a timer. Even if no client visits again ever the timer will fire in t milliseconds